# Is there a rule for abbreviating is to 's?

Tags: apostrophe, contractions, contraction-vs-full-form

Sometimes, we abbreviate sentences like "Nobody is ready" to "Nobody's ready". Is there a rule about this, and is "Nobody's ready" correct or is this considered incorrect?

My apologies if this was already asked, as I couldn't find the answer to this specific case either through Google or by searching on this site.

Comment: It is normal in speech to contract auxiliary verbs with a subject (_He's, they'd, we've_) or a negative (_He isn't, they hadn't, I couldn't_). They are appropriate in written language (when correctly spelled -- beware apostrophe usage) as well. However, some of the subject contractions are ambiguous -- _she'd_ can mean _she would_ (if followed by an infinitive verb form) **or** it can mean _she had_ (if followed by a past participle verb form). Thus _she'd been_ is _she had been_, but _she'd be_ is _she would be_.

Comment: Yeah, I use this sort of thing without thinking twice in non-professional settings. "I wouldn't've done it that way". I wouldn't use it in anything formal, but it is easily understandable and makes communication more natural in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's always correct.  **"X is Y"** can always be shortened to **"X's Y"**.  *Sometimes* it will cause ambiguity, though.  For example, does

> Jorge's toast

refer to the toast owned by Jorge?  Or does it mean

> Jorge is toast

in which case, somebody is going to kill Jorge soon.  Ambiguity isn't ungrammatical English, but it is good practice to try and provide clarity through careful word choice or good contextual information.

Comment: I'm far from convinced any native speaker would ever say *"George's toast"* with the contraction intended to stand for **is**.

Comment: You aren't watching the wrong crap British gangster films.  I recommend a crash course in the complete works of Guy Ritchie and Jason Statham.

Comment: I'll eat my words if you give me a timed reference to an instance in any of Guy Ritchie's films. I think he invariably gets dialogue "right".

Comment: Your point is, in any case, invalid.  I never said that particular example was in common use, I simply offered it as an example of unnecessary ambiguity.  Can you cite any reference to say it is *ungrammatical* English, as opposed to simply unwise (which how I see it)?

Comment: I don't think I'm making a mistake. Your text strongly implies native speakers might perceive ambiguity in the written form. It's effectively meaningless to talk about articulating the *spoken* form differently depending on whether ***George's*** involves a possessive apostrophe or a verb (which *sounds* the same regardless of how it's written or whether the speaker *thinks* he's making a contraction).

Comment: So your problem is with my comment, not my answer, since my comment is where I mentioned a film dialogue (as a joke).  This is not productive.  It seems like ridiculous quibbling.

Comment: I've no argument with the first two sentences in your answer. Nor do I dispute that *without context* there's a potential ambiguity with certain forms. But given it's impossible to distinguish *"George is toast"* from *"George's toast" (the toast belonging to George)* in speech anyway, I think the rest oif the answer isn't really relevant.

Comment: http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0095389/

Comment: This makes sense to me. So, if there's no ambiguity then you can't go wrong by contracting the words. In my example, "ready" isn't something that somebody can "have", it's simply a state of being. If there is an ambiguity, maybe it makes more sense to disambiguate if the context is not enough.